# Django - Group by return only value Sum

Tags: django, group-by

In Django how to perform the following SQL:

```
select sum(valor_aprovado) as vla
from convenios
group by ano
order by ano
```

Desired result:

```
sum_value    |
-------------|
 472837446.59|
 163438615.51|
 448397994.27|
 959203234.57|
 739555948.32|
```

I'm using the following syntax, but I just want it to return the VLA field and not the ANO

```
Convenios.objects.values_list('ano').order_by('ano').annotate(vla=Sum('valor_aprovado')
```

Result:

```
[(2002, Decimal('36246385105.92')), (2003, Decimal('163442260.52')), (2004, Decimal('447464292.52')), (2005, Decimal('948880015.70')), (2006, Decimal('737373593.32')), (2007, Decimal('1449818896.88')), (2008, Decimal('1812889287.82')), (2009, Decimal('2306375485.81')), (2010, Decimal('8730479758.56')), (2011, Decimal('1662088139.88')), (2012, Decimal('1886396504.43')), (2013, Decimal('535507602.69')), (2014, Decimal('4279003118.70')), (2015, Decimal('1883240765.95')), (2016, Decimal('1245291830.72')), (2017, Decimal('2161176688.18')), (2018, Decimal('1346548803.43'))]
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query

```
Convenios.objects.values_list('ano').order_by('ano').annotate(vla=Sum('valor_aprovado')).values('vla')
```